# Does the order of the delegate functions matter in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, delegates

I've integrated the [appsflyer sdk](https://support.appsflyer.com/entries/25458906-iOS-SDK-Integration-Guide-v2-5-3-x-New-API-) within my app.

After submitting the app to the appstore there was a problem.

I've contacted appsflyer support team and they told me that I should change the order of the delegate functions:

**in this way**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker].appsFlyerDevKey = @""; 
[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker].appleAppID = @""; 
}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{ 
//apps flyer Track Installs, updates & sessions(app opens) (You must include this API to enable tracking) 
[[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker] trackAppLaunch]; 
}
```

**instead of**

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
    { 
    //apps flyer Track Installs, updates & sessions(app opens) (You must include this API to enable tracking) 
    [[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker] trackAppLaunch]; 
    }

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker].appsFlyerDevKey = @""; 
    [AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker].appleAppID = @""; 
    }
```

just changing the order of the functions at the delegate file.
How does the order of the functions effect?

EDIT:
the support team send me an email, that the he asked the developer team and it appears that order doesn't matter. it was the support team mistake .

Comment: this doesn't matter at all!

Comment: You should ask the support team, why they think changing order is going to help. surely they are going to tell you "Because code is written in this order in sample code" or something more. try it .

Comment: @pawan no it doesn't matter, it was the support mistake. I've edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No order doesn't matter.. The function called based on Event/State of application not based on written order..

Comment: @david i am agree with Nilesh. function order does't matter.

Answer (score 0):

No the order doesn't matter because they ultimately are methods which are acting as a sort of callback here which get called based on the state in which your application is .